# Puma does not start after server reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, capistrano, puma, start-stop-daemon

I deployed project with capistrano, but puma does not start after server reboot..

I shoul do -> **cap production puma:start** every time

I tried it:

**/etc/init.d/myscript**

```
#!/bin/sh
/etc/init.d/puma_start.sh
```

**puma_start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash 
puma -C /root/project/shared/puma.rb
```

**but, I have error**

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem puma (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@project/bin/puma:22:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@project/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@project/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

if I put in the console `root@host:~# puma -C /root/project/shared/puma.rb` it work, and all okey.

I think I have not correct path to gem puma

How can I do puma autostart after server reboot 
Thank You

Comment: I have also had similar issue with one of the startup script. It was due to the same error, `gem not found`. I solved it by explicitly passing rvm gemset path and execute gem from there.

Like this, `#{HOME_PATH}/.rvm/wrappers/jruby-1.7.13@my_repo/bundle exec rake`

Comment: Some more research and found this puma tool. It does what you need. https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/init.d

It will run puma as a demon service and will also start on server boot

Comment: ok, I created files 'puma' into '/etc/init.d', and 'run-puma' into '/usr/local/bin' , and put line - 'CONFIG=/root/project/shared/puma.rb' into puma file .. and I have  (* Status Puma rack web server puma                                                                                  * --> #!/usr/bin/env isn't there ) .. I don't undertsand how I can start (puma -C /root/project/shared/puma.rb)

Comment: Did you try exact steps as given in that article?

Comment: yes, but I don't understand how it will be work with my rails application .. I run 'sudo service puma start', and see '* => Running the jungle...'   .. I run sudo service puma status , and see * Status Puma rack web server puma       .. but how me do associate my rails application and puma?

Comment: Your original question was about running puma server. And that seems to be working right?

Comment: I understand you, and grateful you,.. but how I can check work puma or not?

Comment: type `puma status` and see what is the output of it

Comment: I see -- >           * Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
ERROR: No application configured, nothing to run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141278/discussion-between-ajinkya-pisal-and-oleg-borodko).

Answer (score 3):

Beginning with Ubuntu 16.04 recommended use **systemctl**. Before I used upstart.
I created this instruction for myself. Maybe it will be useful to someone.

https://gist.github.com/DSKonstantin/708f346f1cf62fb6d61bf6592e480781

---

Instruction:

```
Article: https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md
#1 nano /etc/systemd/system/puma.service
#2 paste from puma.service

Commands:
# After installing or making changes to puma.service
systemctl daemon-reload

# Enable so it starts on boot
systemctl enable puma.service

# Initial start up.
systemctl start puma.service

# Check status
systemctl status puma.service

# A normal restart. Warning: listeners sockets will be closed
# while a new puma process initializes.
systemctl restart puma.service
```

---

puma.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple

User=root
Group=root

WorkingDirectory=<path_to_project>/current
Environment=SECRET_KEY_BASE='<SECRET KEY>'

ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm <ruby_version>@<gemset_name> do bundle exec puma -C <path_to_project>/shared/puma.rb --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm <ruby_version>@<gemset_name> do bundle exec pumactl -S <path_to_project>/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state -F <path_to_project>/shared/puma.rb stop

#Restart=always
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Hi there, links can break at any moment. Please [edit] your answer to include any relevant information directly in the post, and provide the link for reference only.

Comment: Any way for import ENV from the config file (ex: application.yml)?

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a pretty straightforward way of diagnosing and solving this problem:

**1.** Locate your rvm executable.

```
which rvm
```

In my case it was:

```
/usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm
```

...but yours may be **different**! So you have to do that first to find out where your executable is.

**2.** Find out what Ruby version your server is running.

```
ruby --version
```

For me it was 2.6.2.  All you need is that version number. Nothing else.

**3.** Try something like what Konstantin recommended but do this instead:

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory= /var/www/your/current

ExecStart=/usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm 2.6.2 do bundle exec pumactl -S /var/www/your/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state -F /var/www/your/shared/puma.rb start
ExecStop=/usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm 2.6.2 do bundle exec pumactl -S /var/www/your/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state -F /var/www/your/shared/puma.rb stop

# Restart=always
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**4.** Then it's a simple matter of:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable puma.service
systemctl start puma.service
systemctl status puma.service
```

Then that's it! Next time you boot your server, puma should boot fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this http://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-puma-capistrano-nginx-jungle-upstart/

it was help for me ->

```
cd ~
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/puma/puma/master/tools/jungle/upstart/puma-manager.conf
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/puma/puma/master/tools/jungle/upstart/puma.conf
```

Open downloaded puma.conf file and set your system’s user account for setuid and setguid. (in our case we use root account, but it’s recommended to use a less-priviliged account):

```
vim puma.conf

setuid root
setgid root
```

Move downloaded upstart files to /etc/init and create another puma.conf

```
$ sudo cp puma.conf puma-manager.conf /etc/init
$ sudo touch /etc/puma.conf
```

Open /etc/puma.conf and add path to app:

```
/root/name_of_your_app/current
```

Open /etc/init/puma.conf , and to find something similar

```
exec bundle exec puma -C /root/project/shared/puma.rb
```

and replace path to your file puma.rb

Thank you